# libgdx setOrigin and setPosition not working as expected?

Tags: android, libgdx

I create a camera:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(5.0f, 5.0f * h/w);
```

Create a sprite:

```
ballTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/ball.png"));
ballTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(ballTexture, 0, 0, ballTexture.getWidth(), ballTexture.getHeight());
ball = new Sprite(region);
```

Set the origin, size, and position:

```
ball.setOrigin(ball.getWidth()/2,ball.getHeight()/2);
ball.setSize(0.5f, 0.5f * ball.getHeight()/ball.getWidth());
ball.setPosition(0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Then render it:

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
batch.begin();
ball.draw(batch);
batch.end();
```

But when I render it, the bottom left of my ball sprite is at (0, 0), not the center of it, as I would expect it to be because I set the origin to the center of the sprite. What am I missing?

Comment: You cross posted this on SO, then posted the answer you got there as your own here. That's not the way we do things here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's a cross-post from [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322201/libgdx-setorigin-and-setposition-not-working-as-expected). Cross-posting is not allowed on stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

setOrigin does not affect translation, only rotation and scaling.

Thanks to [nEx. Software for their answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11332858/637987).

Comment: As you said, setOrigin() doesn't affect translation, in order to center the sprite at 0,0 you have to setPosition(-w/2, -h/2). Not sure if it is normal to answer your own question in stackoverflow, maybe you have to add a comment instead.